# Non-empty span repeatedly shows up as empty

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy, html

I'm trying to look at a page similar to "http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/snacks/1/1" and for some reason, though I am able to get to the span I want to read, scrapy returns an empty span.

Currently my xpath code is as follows:

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
calorieSpan = hxs.select("//span[@id='KJ_NUTRIENT_1']/text()").extract()
```

This repeatedly returns an empty list. If I remove the "/text()" call then the span is returned as `<span id="KJ_NUTRIENT_1></span>` When I go to the page this span is present, but it is filled. Any ideas on why it's showing up as blank to scrapy? Could is it possible that the values are loaded in by javascript on page load? If so how would I check? If that's the case I could easily switch to casperjs, but since it's much slower I would rather not have to.

Thoughts?

Comment: is the contents of the span dynamically loaded?

Comment: I don't think it is, but I might be wrong. How would I check?

Comment: The contents of the span is dynamically loaded, that might by why it is turning up empty

Comment: If you rt click and say view source and then search of the span you can find that the span is empty

Comment: Is there any way to tell scrapy to wait for it to load, or should I just do the whole thing in casper?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus No. You need to find js which load content and get data from it or find request which get needed data. Scrapy use lxml parser which is not emulate browsers actions (js, css downloading etc)

Answer (score 0):

As this is tagged `python` and `web-scraping`, let's look at a way to do it in python, ten years later:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
browser = uc.Chrome()

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



url = 'http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/snacks/1/1'

browser.get(url)

calories = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "KJ_NUTRIENT_1")))
print('Better late than never:', calories.text)
browser.quit()
```

Result:

```
Better late than never: (0.4 kJ)
```